# Question on Hartshorne exercise II 5.17(e)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm trying to solve exercise II 5.17(e) of Hartshorne:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be an affine morphism between schemes (i.e. preimage of every open affine subscheme of $Y$ is still affine), and let $\mathcal{A}=f_* \mathcal{O}_X$.  Show that $f_*$ induces an equivalence of categories from the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}$-modules (i.e. quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules having a structure of $\mathcal{A}$-module).

In order to prove this question, it suffices to construct a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ for any quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}$-module $\mathcal{M}$, and show the functors $f_*$ and $\tilde{}$ are inverse to each other.

I am trying to construct $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}$ by gluing sheaves: Since $\mathcal{M}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}$-module, $\mathcal{M}(U)$ has an $\mathcal{A}(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))$- module structure. Then we have a sheaf $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}$ on affine open subset $f^{-1}(U)$.  To glue up all these $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}$, we only need to check that, when $U'\subset U$ are open affine subsets, $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}|_{f^{-1}(U')}\simeq \widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U')}$.  I am stuck here, and **my attempt is as follows**:

Let $U=\operatorname{Spec}B,U'=\operatorname{Spec}B',f^{-1}(U)=\operatorname{Spec}A,f^{-1}(U')=\operatorname{Spec}A'$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
f^{-1}(U)=\operatorname{Spec}A @>{f_U}>> \operatorname{Spec}B=U\\
@AAA @AAA \\
f^{-1}(U')=\operatorname{Spec}A' @>{f_{U'}}>> \operatorname{Spec}B'=U'
\end{CD}$$

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B=\mathcal{O}_Y(U) @>>> \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))=A\\
@VVV @VVV \\
B'=\mathcal{O}_Y(U') @>>> \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U'))=A'
\end{CD}$$

Since $\mathcal{M}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}$-module, $\mathcal{M}(U)$ has a $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)=B$-module structure via ring homomorphism $B=\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\to \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))=A$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module implies that $\mathcal{M}|_U\simeq {f_U}_*(\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)})\simeq \widetilde{_B\mathcal{M}(U)}$, where $f_U:f^{-1}(U)=\operatorname{Spec}A\to\operatorname{Spec}B=U$.  Similarly, we have $\mathcal{M}|_{U'}\simeq \widetilde{_{B'}\mathcal{M}(U')}$.  Since $\mathcal{M}$ is quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, $(\mathcal{M}|_U)|_{U'}\simeq \widetilde{B'{\otimes{_B}_B}{\mathcal{M}(U)}}\simeq \mathcal{M}|_{U'} \simeq \widetilde{_{B'}\mathcal{M}(U')}$, which implies that $B'\otimes{_B} _B{\mathcal{M}(U)}\simeq {_{B'}\mathcal{M}(U')}$.

Similarly, $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}|_{f^{-1}(U')}\simeq \widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U')}$ is equivalent to $A'\otimes_A \mathcal{M}(U)\simeq \mathcal{M}(U')$, but how can we get this from $B'\otimes{_B} _B{\mathcal{M}(U)}\simeq {_{B'}\mathcal{M}(U')}$?

**Edit**

It seems that the most important fact in my proof is that, ${f_{U'}}_*(\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U')})\simeq {f_U}_*(\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)})|_{U'}\simeq {f_{U'}}_*(\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}|_{f^{-1}(U')})$.  But how can we get $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}|_{f^{-1}(U')}\simeq \widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U')}$?

Comment: Note that $A \otimes_B B' = A'$ by the universal property of the fiber product: If $p:X \to Y$ and $U \subseteq Y$ open then $p^{-1}(U) = X \times_Y U$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Thank you! Since $B'\otimes_B A=A'$ is a $B$-algebra isomorphism, we can show that $A'\otimes_A \mathcal{M}(U)\simeq B'\otimes_B A\otimes_A \mathcal{M}(U)\simeq B'\otimes_B \mathcal{M}(U)\simeq \mathcal{M}(U')$ as $B$-module in this way, but how can I show that they are isomorphic as $A'$-module?

Comment: You have to verify that the action of $A'$ on both sides of the map $\psi:A' \otimes_A M \to M'$ given by $a' \otimes_A m \mapsto a' \phi(m)$ (where $M = \mathcal{M}(U)$ and $M' = \mathcal{M}(U')$ and $\phi:M \to M'$ is the canonical restriction) is compatible with the map. To be extra sure, you can trace the action of $A'$ through the whole chain of isomorphisms and convince yourself that $\psi$ is the map given by the chain of tensor isomorphisms.

Comment: $\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}$The equivalence $f_*:\mathsf{QCoh}(\sO_X)\to\mathsf{QCoh}(f_*\sO_X)$ for $f$ affine is stated without proof in EGA II: fully faithfulness is (1.4.1); essential surjectivity is (1.4.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand everything you wrote, but here is a way to simplify the situation:

To show that the sheaves glue, you actually only need to consider distinguished open sets $D_U(g)\subseteq U$ (for some $g\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$). This is because for open affines $U,V\subseteq Y$, the affine opens $W\subseteq U\cap V$ which are distinguished both in $U$ and $V$ form a basis of the topology of $U\cap V$.

Now if you have a distinguished open $D_U(g)\subseteq U$, then $f^{-1}D_{U}(g)=D_{f^{-1}U}(f^{\#}(U)(g))$ and thus
$$
\widetilde{\mathcal{M}(U)}(f^{-1}D_{U}(g))\cong\mathcal{M}(U)_{f^{\#}(U)(g)}.
$$
But then as the $\mathcal{A}$-module structure is compatible with the $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module structure via $f^{\#}$, the localisation of $\mathcal{M}(U)$ at $f^{\#}(U)(g)$ as an $\mathcal{A}(U)$-module is the same as the localisation of $\mathcal{M}(U)$ at $g$ as an $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)$-module. But by quasi-coherence we have $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong \mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$, so we are done.

From there you can conclude the glueing, and you can also conclude the case where $U'\subseteq U$ is an arbitrary affine open. I don't know if there is a more straightforward way to do this.

Edit: Because it was wished by the OP, even more precisely:

Notice that $\mathcal{M}(U)_g$, which is a priori only an $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g$-module, naturally has the structure of an $\mathcal{A}(U)_{h}$-module, where $h:=f^{\#}(U)(g)$ for brevity. Indeed, we can define
$$
\frac{a}{h^n}\cdot\frac{s}{g^m}:=\frac{as}{g^{m+n}},
$$
and verify that this endows $\mathcal{M}(U)_g$ with an $\mathcal{A}(U)_{h}$-module structure. It is then straightforward to see that $\mathcal{M}(U)_h\cong\mathcal{M}(U)_g$ as $\mathcal{A}(U)_h$-modules, and also $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{A}(U)_h\cong\mathcal{A}(D_U(g))$-modules.

Edit 2:

To show that $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ is an $\mathcal{A}(U)_g\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$-module homomorphism, denote by $\rho:\mathcal{M}(U)\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ the restriction map from $U$ to $D_U(g)$ (and by $\rho^\mathcal{A}$ resp. $\rho^Y$ the corresponding restriction maps of $\mathcal{A}$ resp. $\mathcal{O}_Y$). By definition of $\mathcal{M}$ being an $\mathcal{A}$-module, this is compatible with the action of $\mathcal{A}(U)$ on $\mathcal{M}(U)$ and $\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$. The mentioned isomorphism is given by
$$
\rho^{\mathcal{M}}_g:\mathcal{M}(U)_g\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))\\
\frac{s}{g^m}\mapsto \rho^{Y}(g)^{-m}\rho^{\mathcal{M}}(s).
$$
Similarly, the isomorphism $\mathcal{A}(U)_h\to\mathcal{A}(D_U(g))$ is given by
$$
\rho^{\mathcal{A}}_h:\mathcal{A}(U)_h\to\mathcal{A}(D_U(g))\\
\frac{s}{h^n}\mapsto \rho^{Y}(g)^{-n}\rho^{\mathcal{A}}(s).
$$
Then we may verify that
$$
\rho^{\mathcal{M}}_g\left(\frac{a}{h^n}\cdot\frac{s}{g^m}\right)=\rho^{\mathcal{M}}_g\left(\frac{as}{g^{m+n}}\right)=\rho^Y(g)^{-(m+n)}\rho^\mathcal{M}(as)=\rho^Y(g)^{-(m+n)}\rho^\mathcal{A}(a)\rho^{\mathcal{M}}(s)=\rho_h^{\mathcal{A}}(a/h^n)\rho_g^{\mathcal{M}}(s/g^m).
$$
But all this blabla hides what is actually going on: you have to crucially use that $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module, so all the restriction maps are compatible with $\mathcal{A}$. Localisation doesn't change anything about this compatibility, because if muliplication is compatible, then division is as well, as soon as it is well defined.

Comment: Thanks for your proof! I still have some questions: Since $\mathcal{M}$ is quasi-coherent over $U$ and $D_U(g)$, we have $\mathcal{M}(U)_g \cong \mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{O}_Y(D_U(g))\cong \mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g$-module.  And we have $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong \mathcal{M}(U)_{f^\#(U)(g)}$ as $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g$-module.  But we want $\mathcal{M}(U)_{f^\#(U)(g)}\cong \mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(D_U(g)))\cong \mathcal{O}_X(U)_{f^\#(U)(g)}$-module. How can we get this?

Comment: Correction:$\mathcal{O}_X(U)_{f^\#(U)(g)}$ should be $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))_{f^\#(U)(g)} $ in the above comment. We have a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g \to\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))_{f^\#(U)(g)}$ and the $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g$-module structure of our modules is from this homomorphism, but I still don’t know what to do next.

Comment: @Eric I added an explanation, does this resolve your remaining doubts?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I have verified that the given definition endows $\mathcal{M}(U)_g$ with an $\mathcal{A}(U)_h$-module structure. 
 I'm sorry but can you explain more about how to show $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{A}(U)_h\cong\mathcal{A}(D_U(g))$-modules? Does the homomorphism $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{A}(U)_h$-module be defined as the given isomorphism $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ as $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)_g$-modules?

Comment: To show that it is an $\mathcal{A}(U)_h$-module homomorphism, we should check this homomorphism commutes with the action of elements of  $\mathcal{A}(U)_h$.  It's easy to see it does commute with $\frac{1}{h}$ by our definition, but how to see it commutes with the action of elements of $\mathcal{A}(U)$?

Comment: @Eric This follows directly from $\mathcal{M}$ being an $\mathcal{A}$-module, doesn't it? I added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Maybe a trivial question: Why is the mentioned isomorphism $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\cong \mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ is induced by the natural homomorphism?  By quasi-coherence, we know that they are isomorphic but I do not know if they are isomorphic by the natural homomorphism you have given.

Comment: @Eric quasi-coherence doesn't just give you that $\mathcal{M}(U)_g$ and $\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ are abstractly isomorphic, it precisely gives you that the restriction map $\mathcal{M}(U)_g\to\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ induces an isomorphism. Just look at the proof (or try to think it through yourself). I mean what other natural map between $\mathcal{M}(U)_g$ and $\mathcal{M}(D_U(g))$ should there be? In this level of generality, it basically only makes sense for it to be the restriction homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}
\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$Some months ago I sent the following proof of Tag [01SB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01SB) to Professor A.J. de Jong so maybe they add it to the Stacks Project. In the meantime before it (might) get accepted, I will post it here in case it's useful to anyone.

> **Lemma.**
> Let $S$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra. An $\mathcal{A}$-module is
> quasi-coherent as an $\mathcal{O}_S$-module if and only if
> it is quasi-coherent as an $\mathcal{A}$-module.

*Proof.*
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{A}$-module.
Assume first $\mathcal{A}$-quasi-coherence,
and choose an open $U\subset S$ and an exact sequence
$$
0\to
\bigoplus_J\mathcal{A}|_U\to
\bigoplus_I\mathcal{A}|_U\to
\mathcal{F}|_U
$$
of $\mathcal{A}|_U$-modules.
Then this is also an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules.
Hence, $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is the cokernel of a morphism
of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules on a scheme and,
thus, $\mathcal{O}_U$-quasi-coherent.

Conversely, assume $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{O}_X$-quasi-coherent.
Pick an open affine $\Spec R=U\subset S$. We have isomorphisms of
$\mathcal{O}_U$-modules $\mathcal{A}|_U\cong\widetilde{A}$ and
$\mathcal{F}|_U\cong\widetilde{M}$, for some $R$-algebra $A$
and some $R$-module $M$. Since $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is also an
$\mathcal{A}|_U$-module, the second isomorphism induces an
$\mathcal{A}|_U$-module structure on $\widetilde{M}$ such that
$\mathcal{F}|_U\cong\widetilde{M}$ promotes to an isomorphism of
$\mathcal{A}|_U$-modules. In particular, $M$ is an $A$-module,
and we can choose an exact sequence
$$
0\to
\bigoplus_J A\to
\bigoplus_I A\to
M
$$
of $A$-modules.
Since localization is exact, for every distinguished open
$D(f)\subset U$, $f\in R$,
the last sequence induces an exact sequence
$$
0\to\bigoplus_J A_f\to\bigoplus_I A_f\to M_f
$$
of $A_f$-modules. Hence we obtain an exact sequence
$$
0\to
\bigoplus_J \widetilde{A}\to
\bigoplus_I \widetilde{A}\to
\widetilde{M}
$$
of $\widetilde{A}$-modules. This means that
$\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{A}$-quasi-coherent.
$\square$

> **Lemma.**
> Let $f : X \to S$ be an affine morphism of schemes.
> Let $\mathcal{A} = f_*\mathcal{O}_X$.
> The functor $\mathcal{F} \mapsto f_*\mathcal{F}$ induces
> an equivalence of categories
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> \text{category of quasi-coherent}\\
> \mathcal{O}_X\text{-modules}
> \end{matrix}
> \right\}
> \longrightarrow
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> \text{category of quasi-coherent}\\
> \mathcal{A}\text{-modules}
> \end{matrix}
> \right\}.
> $$

*Proof.*
In the proof of Lemma [01S8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S8)
it was argued that affine morphisms
are quasi-compact and quasi-separated.
Hence, $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent
$\mathcal{O}_S$-module by [01LC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LC)
(in particular, $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a quasi-coherent
$\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra).
By previous Lemma, $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is
$\mathcal{A}$-quasi-coherent.

We see the fully faithfulness of the
functor from the statement. That is, we verify that
$\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})\to
\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\mathcal{F},f_*\mathcal{G})$ is bijective.
It suffices to see that the morphism of sheaves on $S$
\begin{equation}
\label{map-affine-equivalence-modules}\tag{1}
\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(-)}}
(\mathcal{F}|_{f^{-1}(-)},
\mathcal{G}|_{f^{-1}(-)})\to
\mathcal{H}om_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}
(f_*\mathcal{F},
f_*\mathcal{G})
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism. In turn, it suffices to see that
$$
\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U)}}
(\mathcal{F}|_{f^{-1}(U)},
\mathcal{G}|_{f^{-1}(U)})\to
\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X|_U}
(f_*\mathcal{F}|_U,
f_*\mathcal{G}|_U)
$$
is bijective for $U\subset S$ open affine.
Since $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine, we can assume $S$ is affine,
$X=\Spec A$ and show that
$\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\widetilde{M},f_*\widetilde{N})$
is bijective, where $M,N$ are $A$-modules.
The inverse is defined by considering a
$f_*\mathcal{O}_X$-linear map
$f_*\widetilde{M}\to f_*\widetilde{N}$,
then taking the $A$-linear map on global sections $M\to N$
and then after considering the induced
$\mathcal{O}_X$-linear map $\widetilde{M}\to\widetilde{N}$
([01I7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I7)).
We note that the resulting map
$\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\widetilde{M},f_*\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})$
is compatible with restrictions to distinguished open subsets
$S$ and, hence, it defines a morphism of sheaves on $S$
in the opposite direction as
\eqref{map-affine-equivalence-modules}. On the one hand,
the composite
$\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\widetilde{M},f_*\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})$
is the identity by
[01I7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I7).
On the other hand, to see that the composite
$\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\widetilde{M},f_*\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})\to
\Hom_{f_*\mathcal{O}_X}(f_*\widetilde{M},f_*\widetilde{N})$
is the identity, it suffices to see it on the level of sheaves
(i.e., with the map \eqref{map-affine-equivalence-modules}
and the one in the opposite direction).
In turn, it suffices to see that the composite sheaf map
is the identity on sections over $D(g)\subset U$,
where $g\in\Gamma(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$. Replacing $f:X\to S$ by
$D(f^\sharp(g))=f^{-1}(D(g))\xrightarrow{f} D(g)$,
we have that the diagram
[image]
commutes.

It is left to see essential surjectivity.
For this, we are going to use [01LI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LI)
(note that its proof allows us to take $i_U=\text{id}_{f^{-1}(U)}$).
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}=f_*\mathcal{O}_X$-module.
By previous lemma,
$\mathcal{F}$ is also $\mathcal{O}_S$-quasi-coherent.
For each $U\subset S$ affine, pick an $\mathcal{O}_S(U)$-module
$M_U$ and fix an isomorphism
$\varphi_U:\widetilde{M_U}\to\mathcal{F}|_U$ of
$\mathcal{O}_U$-modules. The $\mathcal{A}|_U$-module
structure on $\mathcal{F}|_U$ induces an
$\mathcal{A}|_U$-module structure on $\widetilde{M_U}$
such that $\varphi_U$ promotes to an isomorphism of
$\mathcal{A}|_U$-modules. Denote $M^U$ to
$\Gamma(U,\widetilde{M_U})$ with the $\mathcal{A}(U)$-module
structure. Then $\widetilde{M^U}$ is a quasi-coherent
module over $f^{-1}(U)$. Note that
$f_{U,*}\widetilde{M^U}=\widetilde{M_U}$
for each open affine $U\subset S$, where
$f_U=f|_{f^{-1}(U)}:f^{-1}(U)\to U$.
For each pair $U,V\subset S$ of affine open subsets with $V\subset U$,
we have an isomorphism of $\mathcal{A}|_V$-modules
$\varphi^U_V:\widetilde{M_U}|_V\to\widetilde{M_V}$
given by the composite
$\widetilde{M_U}|_V\xrightarrow{\varphi_U|_V}
(\mathcal{F}|_U)|_V=
\mathcal{F}|_V\xrightarrow{\varphi_V^{-1}}
\widetilde{M_V}$.
The isomorphism $\varphi^U_V$ is functorial in
the sense that if $W\subset V\subset U\subset S$
are affine open subsets, then
$\varphi^U_W=\varphi^V_W\circ\varphi^U_V|_W$.
In turn, $\varphi^U_V$ gives an isomorphism of
$\mathcal{A}(V)$-modules
$\widetilde{M^U}(f^{-1}(V))
=\widetilde{M_U}(V)
\cong\widetilde{M_V}(V)
=\widetilde{M^V}(f^{-1}(V))$.
Since $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine, this determines an isomorphism of
$\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(V)}$-modules
$\theta^U_V:(\rho^U_V)^*\widetilde{M^U}
=\widetilde{M^U}|_{f^{-1}(V)}
\to\widetilde{M^V}$
such that $f_{V,*}\theta^U_V=\varphi^U_V$
([01I7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I7)).
By the functoriality of $\varphi^U_V$ explained before
and the (fully) faithfulness of $f_{W,*}$,
we deduce condition (d) of [01LI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LI).
Hence, the sheaves $\widetilde{M^U}$ glue to a sheaf
$\mathcal{G}$ over $X$ for which there are isomorphisms
$\theta_U:\widetilde{M^U}\to \mathcal{G}|_{f^{-1}(U)}$
for each open affine $U\subset S$ such that
$\theta^U_V
=\theta^{-1}_V\circ\theta_U|_{f^{-1}(V)}$
for $V\subset U\subset S$ open affine.
For each open affine $U\subset S$,
we have an isomorphism of $\mathcal{A}|_U$-modules
$\mathcal{F}|_U\cong f_*\mathcal{G}|_U$ given by the composite
$$
\mathcal{F}|_U
\xrightarrow{\varphi_U^{-1}}
\widetilde{M}_U
=f_{U,*}\widetilde{M^U}
\xrightarrow{f_{U,*}\theta_U}
f_{U,*}(\mathcal{G}|_{f^{-1}(U)})
=f_*\mathcal{G}|_U.
$$
For $V\subset U\subset S$ open affine, we have
\begin{align*}
(f_{U,*}\theta_U\circ\varphi_U^{-1})|_V
&=f_{U,*}\theta_U|_V\circ\varphi_U^{-1}|_V\\
&=f_{V,*}(\theta_U|_{f^{-1}(V)})\circ\varphi_U^{-1}|_V\\
&=f_{V,*}(\theta_V\circ\theta^U_V)\circ\varphi_U^{-1}|_V\\
&=f_{V,*}\theta_V\circ f_{V,*}\theta^U_V\circ\varphi_U^{-1}|_V\\
&=f_{V,*}\theta_V\circ \varphi^U_V\circ\varphi_U^{-1}|_V\\
&=f_{V,*}\theta_V\circ\varphi_V^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Hence, these isomorphisms glue to an isomorphism of
$\mathcal{A}$-modules $\mathcal{F}\cong f_*\mathcal{G}$
(use [00AN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AN)
or [009U](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/009U)),
and we win.
$\square$